# How to get the correct count for a Lucid Model's Paginate when joining with additional tables

Tags: adonis.js

I have 2 Lucid models: `Ad` and `Campaign`, which are associated using a Many:Many relationship. They have a pivot table which manages the relationship which has additional information, so my table structure is as follows:

- ads

  - id
  - ...
- campaign_ads

  - campaign_id
  - ad_id
  - spend
  - sent
  - clicks
  - leads
  - ftds
- campaigns

  - id
  - ...

I am trying to fetch the results of a `paginate` query using the `Ad` models' `query` function, but in addition to the `Ad` models' fields, I would also like to fetch the sum of `spend`, `sent`, `clicks`, `leads` and `ftds` from the related `Campaign` models' pivots.

I have come up with the following code, which returns the correct information in the collection, but returns an incorrect value for the `count`

```js
const Ad = use('App/Models/Ad');
const query = Ad.query()
                .leftJoin('campaign_ads', 'ads.id', 'campaign_ads.ad_id')
                .select('ads.*')
                .sum('campaign_ads.spend as spend')
                .sum('campaign_ads.sent as sent')
                .sum('campaign_ads.clicks as clicks')
                .sum('campaign_ads.leads as leads')
                .sum('campaign_ads.ftds as ftds')
                .groupBy('ads.id')
                .paginate()
```

I assume that this is related to how the `paginate` function rewrites or performs the query, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: So I have narrowed the issue down to how Adonis's `paginate` function generates the count query. The "original" query generated (for PostgreSQL) is `select "ads".*, sum("campaign_ads"."spend") as "spend", sum("campaign_ads"."sent") as "sent", sum("campaign_ads"."clicks") as "clicks", sum("campaign_ads"."leads") as "leads", sum("campaign_ads"."ftds") as "ftds" from "ads" left join "campaign_ads" on "ads"."id" = "campaign_ads"."ad_id" group by "ads"."id"`. When you replace all of the `select`s with `COUNT(*)`, due to the `groupBy`, the query returns the first "count" group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I noted before in my notes, the problem that I was have was caused by how Lucid's query builder handles the `paginate` function, so I was forced to "roll my own". Here's what I came up with:

```js
paginate (query, page = 1, perPage = 20) {
  // Types of statements which are going to filter from the count query
  const excludeAttrFromCount = ['order', 'columns', 'limit', 'offset', 'group']
  // Clone the original query which we are paginating
  const countByQuery = query.clone();
  // Case Page and Per Page as Numbers
  page = Number(page)
  perPage = Number(perPage)
  // Filter the statments from the array above so we have a query which can run cleanly for counting
  countByQuery.query._statements = _.filter(countByQuery.query._statements, (statement) => {
    return excludeAttrFromCount.indexOf(statement.grouping) < 0
  })
  // Since in my case, i'm working with a left join, i'm going to ensure that i'm only counting the unique models
  countByQuery.countDistinct([this.#model.table, 'id'].join('.'));
  const counts = await countByQuery.first()
  const total = parseInt(counts.count);
  let data;
  // If we get a count of 0, there's no point in delaying processing for an additional DB query
  if (0 === total) {
    data = [];
  }
  // Use the query's native `fetch` method, which already creates instances of the models and eager loads any relevant data
  else {
    const {rows} = await query.forPage(page, perPage).fetch();
    data = rows;
  }
  // Create the results object that you would normally get
  const result = {
    total: total,
    perPage: perPage,
    page: page,
    lastPage: Math.ceil(total / perPage),
    data: data
  }
  // Create the meta data which we will pass to the pagination hook + serializer
  const pages = _.omit(result, ['data'])

  // this.#model references the Model (not the instance). I reference it like this because this function is part of a larger class
  if (this.#model.$hooks) {
    await this.#model.$hooks.after.exec('paginate', data, pages)
  }
  // Create and return the serialized versions
  const Serializer = this.#model.resolveSerializer()
  return new Serializer(data, pages);
}
```

I only use this version of pagination when I detect `group by` in my query, and it follow's Lucid's own `paginate` function pretty closely, and returns identical feedback. While it's not a 100% drop-in solution, it's good enough for my needs

Comment: Hello, how do you use this function?

Comment: Instead of calling the query's `.paginate` method to return the results, you need to pass the entire query object as the first argument of the function. You will need to edit the example though since this was taken as part of a much larger class

Comment: it says that `query.clone()` is not a function

Comment: Check out [the updated example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69941907/10645758)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example usage based on the answer:

```js
const Ad = use('App/Models/Ad');
const query = Ad.query()
                .leftJoin('campaign_ads', 'ads.id', 'campaign_ads.ad_id')
                .select('ads.*')
                .sum('campaign_ads.spend as spend')
                .sum('campaign_ads.sent as sent')
                .sum('campaign_ads.clicks as clicks')
                .sum('campaign_ads.leads as leads')
                .sum('campaign_ads.ftds as ftds')
                .groupBy('ads.id')
const paginate = async (query, page = 1, perPage = 20) {
  // Types of statements which are going to filter from the count query
  const excludeAttrFromCount = ['order', 'columns', 'limit', 'offset', 'group']
  // Clone the original query which we are paginating
  const countByQuery = query.clone();
  // Case Page and Per Page as Numbers
  page = Number(page)
  perPage = Number(perPage)
  // Filter the statments from the array above so we have a query which can run cleanly for counting
  countByQuery.query._statements = _.filter(countByQuery.query._statements, (statement) => {
    return excludeAttrFromCount.indexOf(statement.grouping) < 0
  })
  // Since in my case, i'm working with a left join, i'm going to ensure that i'm only counting the unique models
  countByQuery.countDistinct([Ad.table, 'id'].join('.'));
  const counts = await countByQuery.first()
  const total = parseInt(counts.count);
  let data;
  // If we get a count of 0, there's no point in delaying processing for an additional DB query
  if (0 === total) {
    data = [];
  }
  // Use the query's native `fetch` method, which already creates instances of the models and eager loads any relevant data
  else {
    const {rows} = await query.forPage(page, perPage).fetch();
    data = rows;
  }
  // Create the results object that you would normally get
  const result = {
    total: total,
    perPage: perPage,
    page: page,
    lastPage: Math.ceil(total / perPage),
    data: data
  }
  // Create the meta data which we will pass to the pagination hook + serializer
  const pages = _.omit(result, ['data'])
  
  if (Ad.$hooks) {
    await Ad.$hooks.after.exec('paginate', data, pages)
  }
  // Create and return the serialized versions
  const Serializer = Ad.resolveSerializer()
  return new Serializer(data, pages);
}
paginate(query, 1, 20)
    .then(results => {
        // do whatever you want to do with the results here
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // do something with the error here
    })
```